# Using a variable in Getfiles to find files

Tags: vb.net, file-io

```
Textbox1.Text = part

'searching the folder with key word from Textbox1'

' Only get files that contain the keyword stored in 'part' string
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("d:\data\", "*$part*")

'display the result
Dim dir As String
For Each dir In dirs
    Listbox1.Items.Add(dir)
Next
```

I can't get it to search the folder for the files that contain the keyword in their name. The keyword is stored in the 'part' variable.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like:

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("d:\data\", "*" & part & "*")
```

This will build the string for the filter based on the `part` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner:

```
Listbox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("D:\data\", $"*{Textbox1.Text}*"))
```